# How to Parse XML file in c# (youtube api result)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I'm trying to parse XML returned from the Youtue API. The APIcalls work correctly and creates an XmlDocument. I can get an XmlNodeList of the "entry" tags, but I'm not sure how to get the elements inside such as the , , etc...

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = youtubeService.GetSearchResults(search.Term, "published", 1, 50);
 XmlNodeList listNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");
 foreach (XmlNode node in listNodes)
 {
     //not sure how to get elements in here
 }
```

The XML document schema is shown here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds.html

I know that node.Attributes is the wrong call, but am not sure what the correct one is?

By the way, if there is a better way (faster, less memory) to do this by serializing it or using linq, I'd be happy to use that instead.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some examples reading the XmlDocument. I don't know whats fastest or what needs less memory - but i would prefer Linq To Xml because of its clearness.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = youtubeService.GetSearchResults(search.Term, "published", 1, 50);
XmlNodeList listNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");
foreach (XmlNode node in listNodes)
{
    // get child nodes
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
    }

    // get specific child nodes
    XPathNavigator navigator = node.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select(/* xpath selector according to the elements/attributes you need */);

    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        // f.e. iterator.Current.GetAttribute(), iterator.Current.Name and iterator.Current.Value available here
    }
}
```

and the linq to xml one:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = youtubeService.GetSearchResults(search.Term, "published", 1, 50);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
var entries = from entry in xDoc.Descendants("entry")
              select new
              {
                  Id = entry.Element("id").Value,
                  Categories = entry.Elements("category").Select(c => c.Value)
              };

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    // entry.Id and entry.Categories available here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this has been answered and LINQ to XML is what I'd go with but another option would be XPathNavigator. Something like

```
XPathNavigator xmlNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator xmlitr = xmlNav.Select("/XPath/expression/here")

while (xmlItr.MoveNext()) ...
```

The code is off the top of my head so it may be wrong and there may be a better way with XPathNavigator but it should give you the general idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSD.exe to generate a class based on the schema provided. Once generated, you could then parse the XML response into the strongly typed class.

```
string xmlResponse = GetMyYouTubeStuff();
MyYouTubeClass response = null;
XmlHelper<MyYouTubeClass> xmlHelper = new XmlHelper<MyYouTubeClass>();
response = xmlHelper.Deserialize(xmlResponse);
```

And the class for deserializing it...

```
public class XmlHelper<T>
{
 public T Deserialize(string xml)
  {
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    Byte[] byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(xml);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream);

    T retObj = (T)xs.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);

    return retObj;
  }
}
```

There's also another way [here](http://www.dotneat.net/2007/12/20/QueryingYoutubeAPIUsingC.aspx).